# Correct error type soft 404

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, google-search-console

I try to correct error "soft404"

I read this https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/181708?hl=fr so it's ok i understand.

To correct this error with a personalized page 404 can I do :

```
<?php



    try{
         echo "Error, I fail to load the services I catch It ! (have imagination)";
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        include 'page404.html';
        exit;
    }


?>
```

Comment: if you want to correct your soft 404, just remove "Location" header. That's all

Comment: Yes, that's what Lawrence were talking you. But please distinguish "Page not found" error from "Page exists but have temporary problem loading"

Comment: Yep, I understand the difference thanks to you :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't quite understand the meaning of 404 error and confuse it with a 500 one.
A PDO error has nothing to do with page existence. It is a code error means site experiencing temporary problems. Thus, 500 has to be sent.

It is said that modern PHP versions have to take care of it, but I have some reports that it doesn't.
The only guaranteed way known to me is to use php-fpm, as sending 503 in case of error is one its core features.

Anyway, at least try to set display_errors = off in PHP settings (ini or perdir).
Then change your code to.

```
<?php
echo "Je me connecte a un module foireux et la page est introuvable.";
$pdo = new PDO("n'importe quoi !");
```

and properly configured PHP will respond with 500 *automatically!*

Yet if there is no page found - you indeed have to respond with 404.

```
<?php
$data = DB::getData("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id=?", $_GET['id']);
if (!$data)
{
    throw new http404();
}
```

where `http404()` is a custom exception that have to be processed by a global exception handler. It **have** to send a 404 response. Just a

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
exit;
```

would be enough for Google.

Comment: Soft 404 is just a wrong way of sending 404. What is your question anyway?

Comment: Sorry, can you rephrase? What exactly you want to correct? And Why?

Comment: Google send me a mail because I have error "soft404". Actually, if the page can't be load i do **header("Location: page404.html"); exit;** . It's bad. So if i use **header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");** before, it corrects the error?

Comment: **Please**, provide a **real** case when hit your soft 404. Most likely it have to be 500 instead. Please learn HTTP codes.

Comment: So i can do this in my catch **header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable'); header('Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable'); header('Retry-After: 300');//300 seconds**

Comment: @YourCommonSense heres one https://www.google.com/hfgh%20hfh%20fgh%20fg heres 2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/taggeddfgdf%20gdfg lol

Comment: Yes, if that a temporary error but a **page still exists**, you should not respond with 404. These headers you provided are all right

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇƇhƐȓ0nè yup, both do *hard* 404. What's you're aiming to?